# Why most implementations of pair don't use compression (empty base optimization) by default?

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, std-pair

I have checked [libcxx](https://gist.github.com/EricWF/554eea08b62148ff56ae84e7d32e1fbb), [eastl](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/bonus/compressed_pair.h) and [boost](https://github.com/boostorg/utility/blob/master/include/boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp), all of their pairs are trivial, no ebco. But all of them also implement their own [compressed_pair](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.compressed_pair) and use it in utilities, [unique_ptr(first -> pointer, second -> deleter](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L1031)) for example.

Now that ebco is useful, why don't their pairs not compress by default? Is there any trade-off for this optimization?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide some code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I don't understand how EBCO is even relevant.

Comment: How would you implement a standards conformant pair that uses EBO? Note that compressed_pair has a different API. Nowadays we have tuple anyway. If not for ABI compatibility, implementations could use `[[unique_address]]` in C++20.

Comment: @RichardHodges links updated

Comment: @MarcGlisse They have the same api: second, first, oeprator =, swap... The only difference is compressed_pair will inheritance from the empty elems

Comment: `boost::compressed_pair::first` is a function, not data as in `std::pair`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Opos, my bad. You are right.

Comment: Despite the fact that in C++ 14 `std::pair` has eight constructors, it's supposed to be **simple**. It was originally intended to be a convenient way of writing a `struct` with two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementations of [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) cannot use [empty base optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) (EBO), as the objects it contains are the *member subobjects*, `first` and `second`, and EBO only applies to *base class subobjects*.

Note that implementations of [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) *can* use EBO, as its subobjects are exposed via [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), which allows the use of base class subobjects.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Thomson answered the question.

I would like to add that if performance is important, `std::pair` and `std::tuple` are not your friends. These classes define constructors and assignments which make them non-trivial/non-POD classes even if they contain trivial/POD members, which precludes all optimizations for trivial/POD classes in the standard library.

If possible, instead define a `struct` with no constructors or assignments for the best performance. That also allows for human readable names. [The rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is your best performance friend.